# Are "Scatter Generators" dragging performance down?

Tags: rendering

I started my Blender journey a week ago, since then I'm trying different generators, addons etc.

Nowadays I try to create simple scene which includes only grass, a rock and some ivy.

For grass I used geoscatter and for ivy I used baga ivy generator. But when I add only a little ivy to the scene, fps going down to 10-11 and rendering only 250 frames with wind animation takes hours (even without ivy generate).

My questions are:

- Are there too many faces on the scene?
- Using generators for eveything is a bad idea?
- What I'm doing wrong?

My PC specs:

- Ryzen 5 3600
- GTX 1070
- 16 GB RAM

Here are some screenshots in which you can see faces, fps, statistics etc.;

With ivy:
[image: with ivy]

Without ivy:
[image: without ivy]

Comment: "*Are "Scatter Generators" dragging performance down?*" No, the amount of complex geometry is. Its not that generators are bad per-se, but they can easily add insurmountable amounts of geometry your computer cannot handle. Adding similar complexity through other means would be at least as heavy if not worse. Most good scatter methods have some sort of simplification, like the *Proxy* system in your screenshot.

Comment: I would lower the *Max Samples* render setting (first screenshot). The default value of 4096 for the final render is very high, especially for older hardware. Try 128 samples for render like Blender 2.x had, and 32 instead of 1024 for viewport rendering.